# How to change the highlight colour of tabbar icons? (iPhone/iPad)

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, uitabbar

I have been looking around online for an answer to this question for several days now with no success. Essentially what I want to do is change the highlight colour of the icons in my `UITabBar`. By default they are highlighted in blue when selected, however I have seen several apps that have managed to change this (eg. McDonalds app, shown below).

[image]

What I would like to be able to do is set the highlight colour to red, if this is even possible please can someone help me?

**NOTE:** If it makes things any easier I'm targeting this app at users of `iOS5`+.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can do this using the appearance proxy, new in iOS 5. In your app delegate's didFinishLaunching method:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

In iOS 7 use:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

See the [UITabBar class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more details.

Comment: Awesome Answer! I made a little method to convert hex values to uicolor and passed the colour to his. It worked like a charm! Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

In swift put this:

```
 UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

inside of the app delegate's didFinishLaunching method... Just keeping up with the times.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
[[[UITabBarItem alloc] init] setFinishedSelectedImage:(UIImage *)myImageRed.png withFinishedUnselectedImage:myImage.png];
```